# Getting multiple average aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a query where I'm grouping by smartphone and then by carrier. Inside these nested aggregations, I want to find the avg price, rating, and speed of each carrier for that particular smartphone. This is my current query:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_smartphone": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "smartphone"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_carrier": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "carrier"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "group_by_avg_price": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "price"
              }
            }
          },

            "group_by_rating":{
              "avg":{
                "field": "rating"
              }
            }

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this current query, I'm getting an error saying:

> "type": "parsing_exception",
>       "reason": "Found two aggregation type definitions in [group_by_carrier]: [terms] and [group_by_rating]",

How can I fix this in order to display the correct results of each average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_smartphone": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "smartphone"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_carrier": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "carrier"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "avg_price": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "price"
              }
            },
            "avg_rating":{
              "avg":{
                "field": "rating"
              }
            },
            "avg_speed":{
              "avg":{
                "field": "speed"
              }
            }
          }    
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All sub-aggregations need to be located inside the same `aggs` structure.

Comment: Would it be possible if you could take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45268131/finding-sum-of-average-sub-aggregations